# replace string via re.sub() using a regular expression as replacer

Tags: python, regex, string

```
string = "@ABlue , @Red , @GYellow, @Yellow, @GGreen"
new = re.sub('(@[A-Z][A-Z])', "########" , string)
```

I need a regular expression which is able to check for an @ following by two uppercase letters and than remove the @ and the first uppercase character.cc

Answer (score 1):

Using capturing group and backreference:

```
>>> import re
>>> string = "@ABlue , @Red , @GYellow, @Yellow, @GGreen"
>>> re.sub('@[A-Z]([A-Z])', r"\1" , string)
'Blue , @Red , Yellow, @Yellow, Green'
```

`\1` in the substitution string will be replaced with the first capturing group (The second uppercase letter).

**NOTE** used a `r"raw string literal"`. Otherwise, you need to escape `\`: `"\\1"`

Alternative using [positive lookahead assertion](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html):

```
>>> re.sub('@[A-Z](?=[A-Z])', '' , string)
'Blue , @Red , Yellow, @Yellow, Green'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> new = re.sub(r"@[A-Z]([A-Z])", r"\1" , string)
>>> new
'Blue , @Red , Yellow, @Yellow, Green'
```